# edit path of common stepDefinitions in cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

We got this in our package.json

```
    "stepDefinitions": [
      "./steps/[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "./steps/[filepath].{js,ts}",
      "./steps/common/**/*.{js,ts}"
    ]
```

But I'm encountering **Multiple matching step definitions** error because the file directory structure of my step definition and a common step definition seems to match, both saving the same step but with for a totally different module.

The directory which my step definition is listed is `test/cypress/steps/module1/config/steps.ts` and the common step definition is `test/cypress/steps/common/module3/steps.ts`

So for my question, is there anyway I can get the `module1` and pass it on the package.json with the update common file path of `"./steps/common/<module>/**/*.{js,ts}"`

***P.S. We don't use --spec tag***